# IBM WebSpher MQ Queue.Get() call hangs forever in case of loss in connectivity

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm using IBM MQ version 8.0.0.0 in a .NET application using C#. Now I'm trying to read messages from a queue. I'm using the below code to read the messages from the queue.

```
.....

Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
            props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            props.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);    // Reconnect option

openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, props);

this.queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

....

MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                | MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;

            gmo.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;
            gmo.WaitInterval = 5000;     // I'm specifying this

var message = new MQMessage();
this.queue.Get(message, gmo);        // Waits here forever in case connection is lost to IBM MQ.

.........

.........
```

Now in case, there is a loss of connectivity to the MQ server **AFTER** connection is established but **BEFORE** a queue.Get() call is issued, I'm seeing that the .GET() call waits forever and doesn't stop despite specifying the WAIT_INTERVAL.

Also, I observed that as soon as connectivity is restored, the .Get() call returns immediately with the message that it has read from the queue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit:
Added the queueManager Creation code with the properties, one of which instructs the client to reconnect if possible to the same queue manager.

Answer (score 0):

From this observation:

> Also, I observed that as soon as connectivity is restored, the .Get() call returns immediately with the message that it has read from the queue.

The connection to queue manager was lost when the GET call was in progress. So the MQ .NET client is attempting to reconnect to queue manager. While reconnection attempts are going on, the application will find the method call as 'hanging'. This is normal. So the question is have you enabled automatic reconnection in your application? Show complete code.

**Update**
It's a expected behavior because the Get call is internally attempting to reconnect to queue manager. You can:

1) Reduce the reconnection timeout in mqclient.ini file. An example below.

```
Channels:
MQReconnectTimeout = 100
```

2) Check why queue manager is down and bring it up.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled it. I have updated the question with the queue manager creation code where I have given this instruction to reconnect. Please let me know in case any more information is required.